# Gradle Build Error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle

My apps worked fine until some day I receive this message on Gradle Build.

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.blacktrail.quinielacatamarca"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 13
    versionName "3.47"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
 }
 repositories {
mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')

compile files('libs/htmlcleaner-2.16.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I updated my Android Studio, I cleaned the project I rebuilded the project and the error still.

Any idea on how to resolve this?